# Dinamically growing Array until key input Error: invalid next size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I would to extend the array until the program receive "-1" as input. Every time I extend by 1 the current array but after 7 input I have "invalid next size:0x0000000000d47010"

```
void extend(int *v, int i)
{
    int *p;
    p= (int *) realloc(v, (i+1)*sizeof(int));
    if(p!=NULL)
    v=p;    
}
int main()
{
    int *v;
    v= malloc(sizeof(int));
    int n=0;
    int i=0;

    while(n!=-1)
    {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    v[i]=n;
    extend(v,i);
    i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT
possible solution that made this working

```
void extend(int *v, int i)
{
    int *p;
    p= (int *) realloc(v, (i+1)*sizeof(int));
    if(p!=NULL)
    v=p;    
}

int main()
{
        int *v;
        v= malloc(sizeof(int));
    int n=0;
    int i=0;

        while(n!=-1)
        {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n!=-1)
        {
        extend(v,i);
        v[i]=n;
        i++;
        }
    }

    prodottoScalare(v, i);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters are its local variables. So in the function `extend` in this statement

```
v=p;
```

there is assigned local variable `v` that is destroyed after exiting the function. The original pointer itself used as the argument will not be changed.

You need to pass the original pointer to the function by reference.

Also the logic of this while loop

```
while(n!=-1)
{
scanf("%d", &n);
v[i]=n;
extend(v,i);
i++;
}
```

is incorrect. The entered value by the `scanf` can be equal to -1 or the end of the stream can be encountered. Nevertheless the array is extended.

Also you should free all allocated memory.

Take into account that in C main without parameters should be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t extend( int **a, size_t n, int value )
{
    int *p = realloc( *a, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        *a = p;
        ( *a )[n++] = value;
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int *a = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    int value;

    while( scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 && value != -1 )
    {    
        n = extend( &a, n, value );    
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 -1
```

then the program output will look like

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Another function's implementation can look like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_Bool /* or int */ extend( int **a, size_t n )
{
    int *p = realloc( *a, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
    _Bool /* or int */ success = p != NULL;

    if ( success ) *a = p;

    return success;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int *a = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    int value;

    while( scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 && value != -1 )
    {    
        if ( extend( &a, n ) ) a[n++] = value;    
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

The result will be the same as in the first demonstrative program for the same input.

Comment: Your solution could works, I changed the answer and put a solution, it works but is it wrong?

Comment: @user4789408 The function in the new your solution has the same problem with passing the original pointer by value instead of by reference.:)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the pointer v `int *v`of the function `extend` is passed by value, assignment statement `v=p` would not change the value passed to function `extend`. So, argument passed by reference here for `int *v`:

```
void extend(int *&v, int i)
{
    int *p;
    p= (int *) realloc(v, (i+1)*sizeof(int));
    if(p!=NULL)
    v=p;    
}
int main()
{
    int *v;
    v= malloc(sizeof(int));
    int n=0;
    int i=0;

    while(n!=-1)
    {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    v[i]=n;
    extend(v,i);
    i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no referenced types in C.:)